# Why doesn't this webworker respond to a posted message?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-worker

I am working on a React project, and I have this code:

Here, I initialize a web-worker and post a message when the `Documentation` component is loaded.

```
function Documentation() {
  const [result, setResult] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('ran');
    const worker = new Worker('../../Workers/SolveWorker.js');

    worker.postMessage({ type: 'start', data: [5, 10] });

    console.log(worker);


    return () => {
      worker.terminate();
    };
  }, []);
  
  ...
```

Inside `../../Workers/SolveWorker.js`, I have my worker respond to an event:

```
/* eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-globals */
self.onmessage = function (e) {
  console.log("Worker: Message received from main script");
};
```

When I load this component, my message appears to be posted but I never receive a response from the web worker. I've looked at the API but have been unable to figure out what I am doing wrong. Additionally, I get this error: `SolveWorker.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at SolveWorker.js:1:1)`

I believe this is somehow relating to my HTML file (when I click this error in chrome dev tools it opens up my HTML), but I’m not really sure in what way.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: is your path to your worker script correct? sounds like a 404

Comment: I believe it should be correct, I double checked and I have an autocomplete for pathing set up.

Comment: When you call `const worker = new Worker('../../Workers/SolveWorker.js');` your browser will go try to fetch `'../../Workers/SolveWorker.js'`. IIRC the path is relative to the *document root* like it would be for a script tag src, not the file where the worker is created. The reason I don't exactly remember is that I generally use a rollup plugin to inline my workers.

Comment: Jared, my dir is: `cube-explorer/src/Workers/SolveWorker.js`, I tried putting in: `const worker = new Worker('./src/Workers/SolveWorker.js');` but that doesn't work, have I misunderstood?

Comment: Nevermind, it needs to go in `public`, thanks, feel free to leave a formal response if you want an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `const worker = new Worker('../../Workers/SolveWorker.js');` your browser will go try to fetch `'../../Workers/SolveWorker.js'`. The path is relative to the *document root* (i.e. where your `index.html` file is located, sounds like `/public` in your case) like it would be for a `script` tag `src`, **not** the *Javascript* file where the worker is created.

Alternatively, you can use a [rollup plugin to inline workers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-web-worker-loader) in which case your file path would be correct because it would go through the normal node resolution algorithm at build time.